# Sharing a PDF file from my app directory with another application works but opening it does not

Tags: android, file-sharing, android-fileprovider

I'm using a fileprovider to save and retrieve PDF files generated by my application. I wanted to share and open these files with other PDF applications. Sharing is working but opening isn't. Here's the code for both sharing and opening the PDF files:

Sharing:

```
    private void shareTheFile(int position) {
    try {
        File docPath=new File(SavedPdfActivity.this.getFilesDir(),"Documents");
        Log.d(TAG, "shareTheFile: document dir path="+docPath.getAbsolutePath());
        File file = new File(mList.get(position).getFilePath());
        Log.d(TAG, "shareTheFile: file path as saved in db="+file.getAbsolutePath());
        String fileName=file.getName();
        File newFile=new File(docPath, fileName);
        Log.d(TAG, "shareTheFile: new file path="+newFile.getAbsolutePath());
        Uri uri= FileProvider.getUriForFile(SavedPdfActivity.this, "com.rewoke.prixpi.pdfprovider", newFile);
        Log.d(TAG, "shareTheFile: uri="+uri.toString());
        Intent intentShareFile = new Intent();
        intentShareFile.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intentShareFile.setDataAndType(uri, getContentResolver().getType(uri));
        intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mList.get(position).getFileName());
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        if (intentShareFile.resolveActivity(pm) != null) {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentShareFile, "Share file"));
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "shareTheFile: error msg="+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and Opening the PDF:

```
 private void openThePdf(int position) {
    File docPath=new File(SavedPdfActivity.this.getFilesDir(),"Documents");
    File file = new File(mList.get(position).getFilePath());
    String fileName=file.getName();
    File newFile=new File(docPath, fileName);

    try {
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(SavedPdfActivity.this, "com.application.name.pdfprovider", newFile);
        Intent openIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        openIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        if (openIntent.resolveActivity(pm) != null) {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(openIntent, "Open file"));
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "openThePdf: error msg="+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error as this when trying to open the file with Drive PDF Viewer app:

```
openFd: java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

My fileprovider:

```
  <provider
        android:authorities="{$appliation_name}.pdfprovider"
        android:name=".helper.CustomFileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths"/>
    </provider>
```

My logs:

```
2019-12-23 12:17:26.100 19822-19822/com.rewoke.prixpi D/SavedPdfActivity: shareTheFile: document dir path=/data/user/0/com.rewoke.prixpi/files/Documents
2019-12-23 12:17:26.100 19822-19822/com.rewoke.prixpi D/SavedPdfActivity: shareTheFile: file path as saved in db=/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.rewoke.prixpi/files/Documents/PrixpiPDF_2019-12-357 11:30:503867655244253323634.pdf
2019-12-23 12:17:26.100 19822-19822/com.rewoke.prixpi D/SavedPdfActivity: shareTheFile: new file path=/data/user/0/com.rewoke.prixpi/files/Documents/PrixpiPDF_2019-12-357 11:30:503867655244253323634.pdf
2019-12-23 12:17:26.101 19822-19822/com.rewoke.prixpi D/SavedPdfActivity: shareTheFile: uri=content://com.rewoke.prixpi.pdfprovider/my_docs/PrixpiPDF_2019-12-357%2011%3A30%3A503867655244253323634.pdf
```

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException` is a pretty obvious error message :(  Q: Did you go into Android Studio, set a breakpoint, and step through the code in `openThePdf()`?  Are the values for `docPath` and `fileName` what you expect?  Can you go into A/S FileViewer and verify the file exists on the handset?

Comment: there's a file chooser that pops up, so i dont think there's an error with parsing the uri(meaning the docPath and fileName are fine right?) from the file path. and yes, the file does exist on the handset. Sharing the file works just fine as well

Comment: change this line  android:name=".helper.CustomFileProvider" to android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"

Comment: Dude - if you have a debugger, *USE* it!  Also: Sandeep dhiman has a good point - maybe you're using `android.support`, but your build.gradle is configured for `androidx` (or vice versa),  Please: 1) confirm whether you should be using androidx vs. android.support, 2) Step through the debugger and confirm EACH variable leading up to the "file not found" exception, and 3) *UPDATE YOUR POST WITH WHAT YOU FIND*!

Comment: 1) i'm using androidx, however i cant change the name of the provider as I'm using a 3rd party library that uses a fileprovider (having two providers with the same name was giving me manifest merger failed error) 2) I have updated the post with logs for the shareTheFile() 3) I'm unable to use the file obtained from the line "File file=new File(mList.get(position).getFilePath()" directly for parsing the Uri as it was giving me an error of "Failed to find configured root that contains <filepath>"

Comment: Ok, the problem was in the xml file of the provider: I should've been using <external-files-path> instead of <files-path> tag. So now I'm able to parse uri from the file obtained from mList.get(position).getFilePath(). Thanks @FoggyDay